# can't save positions of image after resizing, scaling and dragging through stickerView library

Tags: android

image demo link after manipulation:

[image: image demo link after manipulation]

I am not be able to save the positions of view that are manipulated by stickerView library like resizing, rotating and dragging to particular position because i need that positions for editing that page so that can add new components to existing one but for that old images and view should be saved at their last positionsenter

Answer (score 0):

This is now Solved !!
In this library ,in StickerView.java class there is function calculate() which has return type StickerPropertyModel which has all values regarding stickerview like size,x,y pos on screen ,its scale etc.

Comment: how to set saved sticker property to stickerview

Comment: @Ram ,there would be a function in StickerView class i.e "setbitmap" in which you will find there matrix variable in which you can set its various attributes
 matrix.setRotate(rotate);
        matrix.postTranslate(x, y);
matrix.postScale(-,-);
mBitmap = bitmap;
        setDiagonalLength();
        initBitmaps();
        invalidate();

Comment: and also make correct size bitmap before setting attributes.
public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newWidth, int newHeight) {
        int width = bm.getWidth();
        int height = bm.getHeight();
        float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
        float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
          bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);
        bm.recycle();
        return resizedBitmap; }

Answer (score 0):

I used wupanjie Stickerview and it have getmatrix method for stickers. By saving that values internally you can again set the matrix values using setmatrix method. Btw mentioning which stickerview library you have used will be helpful for others.